# How to add Days from a column to a current Date in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am writing this sql to dynamically calculate certain number of days as below. But I don't know how to make it work because I keep getting the error.

```
select Current Date + ( Dynamic numbr of days calculation here ) from  TableName
```

Usually all the guides shows examples as   Current Date + 1 Day  (this works but not the above)  Any ideas how can I get it to work from ?

Comment: And the error is? - just to clarify.

Comment: Your given example works just fine on my (iSeries, V6R1) system:  `SELECT CURRENT_DATE + numericTableColumn DAYS from tableName`.  Or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: in addition to the error you are getting, providing the table definition and your "dynamic calculation" would help.

Answer (score 12):

> select  Current Date + **Dynamic numbr** DAYS   FROM TableName

e.g.

```
select Current Date + 15 DAYS  from TableName
```

here 15 is dynamic number.

Comment: I did tried it out It doesn't work out. ;(  (this calculation does returns an integer but it doesn't go with that combination)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + (your dynamic numeric field) DAYS FROM FILE_NAME
```

Example based on AS400:

1)

```
SELECT CURDATE() + (FLDA) DAYS FROM FILEA
```

2)

```
SELECT CURDATE() + 8 DAYS FROM FILEA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT                                            
 DATE(DTE_BILL_EFFCTV - 301 DAYS)                  
 FROM BILL_ACCT                 
 WHERE                                             
 DTE_BILL_EFFCTV > DATE(CURRENT DATE - 300 DAYS) ;
```